# Solve the functional equation, $f(x+y+1)= \left(\sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{f(y)}\right)^2$

Tags: functional-equations

Solve the functional equation, find all real valued functions $f(x)$ s.t.

$$f(x+y+1)= \left(\sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{f(y)}\right)^2$$

given $f(0)=1$.

I reached to a point that $4f(x)=f(2x+1)$

Comment: Hint: For which set of values $x$ can, you show that $f(x)=(x+1)^2$?

Comment: Gimme more... :-)

Comment: but how to prove it

Comment: How to prove what? That f(x)=(x+1)^2 when x is an integer? That should be *very* doable...

Comment: but for real.???

Comment: As I said: *gimme more...* If you know f(x) for x integer, for which other values of x can you deduce f(x)?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is a solution and define $g$ by $g(t)=\sqrt{f(t-1)}$, then $g(1)=1$ and $g(t+s)=g(t)+g(s)$ for every $(t,s)$, that is, $g$ is *additive*.

Linear functions are additive but whether or not adding the hypothesis of continuity is necessary for additive functions to be linear depends on the axiom of choice. That is, with the axiom of choice, there exists additive functions besides the linear ones. For an example, complete $\{1\}$ to a Hamel basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space and let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the unique linear function such that $g(1)=1$ and $g(b)=0$ for every $b$ in $B$, $b\ne 1$. Every non linear additive function is discontinuous everywhere.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) or even [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57426/are-there-any-non-linear-solutions-of-cauchys-equation-fxy-fxfy-wit) for less sketchy explanations.

**Edit:** Actually, the conditions that $g$ is additive *and nonnegative everywhere* suffice to conclude. To wit, for every solution $g$, $g(1+0)=g(1)+g(0)$ hence $g(0)=0$, and $g(1-1)=g(1)+g(-1)$ hence $g(-1)=-g(1)=-1$. Since $g(-1)=\sqrt{f(-2)}$, this is absurd, hence the original equation has no solution.